# Set ion-select text

Tags: ionic4

When the ion-select box is open, I need the label text to be different.  Somehow, I can't seem to find a working solution I can figure out.  The pictures below is my goal (achieved through changing the element in browser ATM.)  Also, don't know how to change the size of those pictures.  Sorry.

[image]
[image]

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Water Source</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="waterSource" multiple="true">
    <ion-select-option name="Aquifer">Aquifer</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="CityWater">City Water</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="Lake">Lake</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="Pond">Pond</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="River">River</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="RuralWater">Rural Water</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="Well">Well</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="Other">Other</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
  <ion-input *ngIf="!customers.surveyCompleteDate" formControlName="waterSource" type="string"></ion-input>
  <ion-input *ngIf="customers.surveyCompleteDate" formControlName="waterSource" readonly></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#properties)**, you can use the `interfaceOptions` property to set a different title for the alert (among other things).

Please take a look at **[this stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64383625?file=src/app/app.component.html)**.

[image: Demo]

### Component

```
// ...
public customOptions: any = {
  header: "Pick all that apply"
};
// ...
```

### Template

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Water Source</ion-label>
  <ion-select [interfaceOptions]="customOptions" multiple="true">
    <ion-select-option name="Aquifer">Aquifer</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="CityWater">City Water</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="Lake">Lake</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="Pond">Pond</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="River">River</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="RuralWater">Rural Water</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="Well">Well</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option name="Other">Other</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Please also keep in mind that you can set a `subHeader` and even a `message` in case you want  "Water Source" to be the main title of the alert, and show "Select all that apply" as a sub header or message since that sounds like a hint to the user but not the main title of the alert.